# Ridge regression in matlab

Tags: matlab, linear-regression

I have this doubt about the ridge regression in matlab. They have mentioned at http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/ridge.html, that ridge regression actually mean centers and make the std equal to 1 for the predictors. However, I could see that it doesn't. For e.g.

Let my x be

```
 1     1     2
 1     3     5
 1     9    12
 1    12    50
```

Let my y be

```
1
2
3
4
```

It doesn't do any normalization of the xs to 0 mean and unit variance. Any clarifications what's going on? I mean ridge should do normalization of the data i.e x to 0 mean and unit variance and then calculate the coefficients. I was expecting Ridge(y,x,0,0) to give me result of  R=inv(x'*x)*x'y  where R takes x and y normalized

Answer (score 4):

The output must be the same, ridge regression only makes the calculation more stable numerically (less sensitive to multicollinearity).

**== UPDATE ==**

Now I understand better what you ask :) The [documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/ridge.html) says:

> b = ridge(y,X,k,scaled) uses the {0,1}-valued flag scaled to determine
>   if the coefficient estimates in b are restored to the scale of the
>   original data. ridge(y,X,k,0) performs this additional transformation.

You've set both the third and the fourth parameters to 0, which means that the ridge parameter is zero, and the result won't be scaled, so it should be the same as what you get with `inv(x'*x)*x'y` (this is what the ridge regression formula becomes if the ridge parameter `k` is set to 0).

Comment: Doesn't it do the mean centering and changing the standard deviation to 1 to the data?

Comment: No I meant this By default, b is computed after centering and scaling the predictors to have mean 0 and standard deviation 1. Why doesn't ridge do it? I don't see the xs centered to 0 and have std to 1

Comment: You can find the derivation of both inv(x'*x)*x'*y and ridge regression here: http://www.cs.utah.edu/~piyush/teaching/6-9-print.pdf